# Remove the red outline on form elements that fail validation in drupal

Tags: drupal, drupal-themes, drupal-theming, drupal-forms

When a drupal form fails validation, it is redrawn with the elements that failed validation surrounded in a red border.  Drupal does this by adding the `error` class to the input elements, and specifing a 2px red border on input.error elements in `system.css`.

Without modifying this stylesheet, how can I remove the red border on a specific form only, while using the default behavior on the rest of the site?

I believe the solution might require using a custom `theme_form_element`, but I can't figure out how to customize a single form only.

Note that I would like to do this without having to resort to this jQuery trick (which does work):

```
$("#edit-name").removeClass('error');
```

Comment: While I can change the border color for these specific elements in CSS, I can't get back to the default border for the `input` elements.  So I could make the border green instead of red, but I can't get the normal browser style back.  So unless I'm missing something obvious, I don't think a pure-CSS solution exists for this particular problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to remove the error class from the form items. This can be done by overwriting the theme functions, in `theme_textfield`, `theme_textarea` ... (there is one for each type)

Take a look at `$element['#attributes']['class']` which contains the error class.

**EDIT**
To do it for a specific form element or form you can use the `#theme` attribute or either form or element you want to change the theming function for.

Comment: Can this be done inside of a module?  I seem to be having some trouble getting it to work.

Comment: Your method works (putting it in the theme), but it modifies all forms on my site instead of just a specific one.  I think I will stick with my jQuery solution for now, even though I don't like it.  Thanks for your help though!

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is not to try to modify the markup Drupal is spotting out, but instead to change the styles assocaited with the `error` class.

You can do that without modifying system.css. Simply add a new stylesheet in your theme (or using an existing one!). Use the Cascading nature of CSS to change the way elements with errors appear.  Add something like:

```
.error {
  border: 0;
}
```

... and you are done.

To target only one specific form, add another selector, like so:

```
#my-specific-form .error {
  border: 0;
}
```